# How to perform operations based on user's local date time on your servers

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, jscript

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. I also have an scheduler running on my servers. Now the user can specify when some operation needs to be executed based on their local time.

Also, when they submit requests, I use the following JScript method to get their UTC offset:

```
var date = new Date();
var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
```

Using that I can use the following C# method on the server to calculate if the time that they specified is equal to their local time and if so I perform the operation:

```
DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddMinutes((-1)*utcOffset);
```

Now, I think this is buggy when it comes to daylight savings. So if DST is off, and they set the schedule to run in 4 months, by that time their offset will be different (i.e. +/- 60 min). So my schedule I believe will run one hour early or late.

How do I solve this? I have gone through many similar questions on Stackoverflow or other places but couldn't find something suitable.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You could also save the date and time as UNIX time milliseconds. On the client-side, you can call the `const scheduledUnixTimeMilliseconds = new Date('2020-12-25 00:00:00.000Z').getTime()` function to get the current UNIX time in milliseconds and send it to the server. Once you store it there, your scheduler can do a simple comparison between the stored time and the current UNIX time in milliseconds and run the scheduled task.

```
// Sent from the client side using Date.getTime() on the declared date
long userScheduledUnixTimeMilliseconds = GetUserScheduledUnixTimeMilliseconds();
long currentUnixTimeMilliseconds = System.DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

if (currentUnixTimeMilliseconds >= userScheduledUnixTimeMilliseconds)
{
    RunScheduledTask();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So this might work, but I need more clarifications please. So the ``currentUnixTimeMilliseconds``, is in UxMs which even though is calculated on the server, doesn't make any difference and still we can work with. However, ``userScheduledTime ``, doesn't make sense to me. You are saying in your comment it is the user's/client's time when they submit the request, so, then it is not the scheduled date/time they have in mind. Which means it can't be used to compare and trigger the task. I am probably missing your point.

Comment: @Stackedup Sorry, I messed up the first time. The user probably won't schedule anything for the current time (silly me). You can use the `getTime` function on any JS `Date` object to get the UNIX time milliseconds for his declared date.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Unfortunately, I can't get the future date's details on the client. This is mainly because, the user can assemble instructions that contain different types of dates and send it to the server and these instructions gets parsed on the server. That is why I need some mechanism where I could use their ``locale and current date`` info to make the decision on the server about future dates.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use **UTC time** when there are time calculations/comparisons involved

```
DateTime.UtcNow
```

You can use `AddHours(), AddMinutes()` functions to convert **UTC** Time to required time zones this

```
DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours()
DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes()
```

Comment: Thanks Adarsh for your reply. I agree with you but the problem I have is a bit different from most cases.